# malloc error when migrate in Django using mySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, django-database

I'm using Django in VSCode and want to connect to the MySQL database, I've created the database in MySQL. When changing the database configuration from mysqlite to MySQL in settings.py, and do the migrate, the error pops up (in the picture below). Basically it says malloc error and asks me to set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

I have no idea of what's going on here. Anyone knows how to fix this error? The error message disappears once I changed the settings back to sqlite, it only happens when using MySQL.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiyWy.png)

[screenshot of error_updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIWIL.png)

Comment: did you install mysqlclient?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/#mysql-notes

Comment: also malloc is a memory allocation, you dont need to do it with python, python does it for you. This is not your problem, attach all error code here, you are looking in wrong direction

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I installed mysqlclient. The screenshot I put here is all the error info I got after running 'python manage.py migrate'. Both Django and mysqlclient are up-to-date.

Comment: this cant be full error screenshot, please attach full screenshot, don't cut it

Comment: I've uploaded another screenshot called 'screenshot of error_updated', this is what I actually got after running migrate.